# Can't use Wine version 7.2

Tags: command-line, window, winetricks

When I use the command winecfg, a window is created but doesn't open.It doesn't display the window.
Here is the output

```
winecfg
0100:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x25a450, 1): stub
0100:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0001005A, 0025A450): stub
0050:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x257578, 0): stub
0050:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00010020, 00257578): stub
```

I cannot open the window for wineconfiguration.
Here what it shows me, there is the config without the window.
How to show the window ?
[image]

**I'm using wine7.2 version.
I installed wine7.2 with these commands :**

```
tar xf [filename]

This will expand the contents of the file to a folder. Then the commands are, from the folder:

./configure
./configure --without-freetype

make

sudo make install
```

Comment: Hello. If the intention of the pictures to show the text in the tiny terminal windows they are not doing the job? If so do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question.

Comment: Which version of wine is this? How did you install it?